# compare several columns grouped by a list pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
    A0   B0   C0   D0   E0   F0  G0   A1   B1   C1   D1   E1   F1  G1  label
0  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5   True
1  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   7  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5  False
2  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   7  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   7   True
3  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   6  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   6   True
4  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   6  False
```

I want to compare only df['G0'] and df['G1'],

but after comparing the previous columns
(A0 vs A1, B0 vs B1, C0 vs C1, etc, etc)
and keeping them all the same always.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show the expected result.

Comment: `label` column already exists in your dataframe?

Comment: Please read this advice; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can split your dataframe into two parts then use `numpy` to compare element-wise them without any index. Assuming `label` column does not exist before.

```
df['label'] = (df.iloc[:, :7].to_numpy() == df.iloc[:, 7:].to_numpy()).all(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
    A0   B0   C0   D0   E0   F0  G0   A1   B1   C1   D1   E1   F1  G1  label
0  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5   True
1  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   7  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5  False
2  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   7  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   7   True
3  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   6  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   6   True
4  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   5  1.3  2.4  1.5  2.0  2.0  3.2   6  False
```

Note: I used `.iloc` to split your dataframe evenly but there are other methods like `filter` to select columns based on your column names.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but why not just do `df['label'] = (df['G0'] == df['G1'])`?

Comment: Because in order to compare df['G0'] and df['G1'] I need to compare the other columns first.

Comment: @rnv86. So does it solve the problem or something wrong?